# How do I position a web part at the top right hand corner of a zone?

Tags: web-part, web-part-zone

I have added a webpart to  a page containing several zones. I have added it to the top right zone but it is appearing more or less in the middle of the page, see image below. How can I force it to the top right hand corner of the zone?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Is this a web part page or a wiki page? The specifics may be slightly different in the two cases. In SharePoint 2013 I think they changed the naming to the more ambiguous "Page" vs. "Site Page", but one of the most obvious differences is that a web part page's layout (the quantity and arrangement of the web part zones) is fixed when the page is created, whereas a wiki page's layout can be changed at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the **width / float** properties of the **webpart zones** using CSS

You have to add css to **MasterPage** or any of the **page layout** that the page in which you are adding your webpart is using.

Comment: You can also add the css to a Content Editor Web Part, which is often easier if you only want to do this on one page.

Comment: yeah thats true!

Comment: Thanks for your responses. This is a web part page and is the only one I need to amend the layout for. I am pretty green when it comes to SharePoint and the code that would be needed to do this. Would you be able to give me some example of code to add to a Content Editor web part?